# How many homomorphically irreducible trees can be drawn where each dot is joined to exactly $3$ others with $n>4$?

Tags: logic, graph-theory

Out teacher posed this in our last class but didn't say if this was impossible or not

So far I have been unable to find any homomorphically irreducible trees where each dot is joined to exactly 3 others? ($n>4$)

[image: Example of trees]

I thought that I could use the Seven Bridges of Konigsberg problem to link it to the problem making the landmasses dots and the bridges the connections between them. But so far I have derived nothing from it except that an odd number of bridges will make it impossible to circle the full area and that maybe that means that it cannot occur in the trees. Just a jab into the dark
[image: Bridges of Konigsberg Diagram]

So is this impossible?
And if so what would be the mathematical way to prove it isn't

Also is it even possible if we allow loops to occur in the tree unconventionally?

Comment: What do you mean by "tree"? The graph in your picture is not a tree, in the standard meaning of the term (connected acyclic graph). A finite tree in that sense *can't* have each dot joined to $3$ others. And what is $n$, the number of lines or the number of dots or something else?

Comment: @bof n is the number of dots, the diagram is unrelated to the question just used it as an example for the Konigsberg problem. I've attached a diagram of a tree example above

Comment: A graph with $n$ dots, each dot joined to exactly $3$ others, must have exactly $\frac{3n}2$ lines (so $n$ most be even), but a tree with $n$ dots must have exactly $n-1$ lines. A tree with more than one dot must have at least $2$ *leaves*; a leaf is a dot which is joined to exactly one other dot. So there is no such thing as a tree where each dot is joined to $3$ other dots, unless we're talking about **infinite** trees. Maybe the condition was supposed to be, each **non-leaf** dot is joined to exactly $3$ other dots?

Comment: "Homeomorphically irreducible" seems redundant, all that means is that no node is joined to exactly two other nodes, which is already stated.

Comment: @bof yes it would seem so. Just reiterating what my teacher said

Comment: @bof your explanation was what I was thinking. as the tree must have 2 leaves which only join with another dot. That's what confused me. Now say you were to break the rule in this problem that no loops can occur would their still be an example for where the conditions are true?

Comment: You could add a loop to each leaf, raising its degree (valency) to $3$, though it wouldn't be a legitimate tree any longer. That seems equivalent to the interpretation I suggested: for even $n\ge4$ count the different trees on $n$ dots where each dot is joined to either $1$ or $3$ other dots. There will be $\frac n2-1$ dots joined to $3$ others, and $\frac n2+1$ leaves.